# How to deform mesh along another mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

I want to create a non-destructive depression to achieve something like this:

[image]

The problem is that I need to flatten the area just around and under the text like a depression.

I followed this tutorial (last part: Suzy in snow) but it no longer works on recent blender versions. The nodes have changed and/or removed a lot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKDJ5QvhLIw

I also tried shrinkwrap, hook, and Lattice but none work any good. Here is the low poly mesh:

[image]

Comment: you could either do it with a normal map, or select some faces around the text and move them?

Comment: @moonboots I want the mesh to be non-destructive. In order to move the faces, I have to apply level 1 of subdivision which makes very hard to control other parts of the mesh. I have updated the question.

Comment: if Chris's answer doesn't work, then use a normal map?

Comment: @moonboots I need it to be physically there as the text would lie flat on it. Right now it is a curved mesh.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be...

Use geometry nodes with this node setup:

[image]

I am just creating a bounding box of the text, which then will be used for the vertex weight proximity modifier to set the weights of my vertex group, which then will be displaced by the displace modifier.

Modifiers on my box/car:

[image]

result:

[image]

non-destructive:

[image]

Here is a video tutorial: https://youtu.be/OmUDUsXkTns

Comment: so it works on the text's bounding box, not on the text mesh itself? Or does it just look like that because of the intensity / depth of the deformation?

Comment: Yes, it works on the bounding box. You could stop using the bounding box, I tried this before. Then it would only use the text mesh - but I think the result isn’t as good as with bounding box.

Comment: I am having a hard time following this. The geometry node goes to the fake bounding box created on the Text via Geometry nodes. Then the other object where the depression needs to be there has all those vertex weight modifiers?

Comment: i added a link to the tutorial to my answer. If you still have questions, just ask ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I did everything right but somehow it's not giving the effect properly, maybe because you subdivided the mesh before and there are many vertices to work with. But my model is very low poly and maybe that's why it's not working properly. The geometry node tutorial in my link will work cause it will consider the subdivision. But the nodes are all different now.

Comment: So you are satisfied or still problems?

Comment: Still problem. I will show you later ow it works in my case. @Chris

Comment: A blend file would help me most to check it out…

Comment: @Chris https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsS-Et1q_EmTgb98YWIbxXaPEGi2hA?e=Ft8zO4

Comment: unfortunately i cannot get it done :( it's pretty weird because yours is indenting inward. Even changing low and high didn't work. i tried it 30 mins now. and i have no idea why it's not working... maybe Blender has a problem because you already did manually indent it a bit...but this is just a guess.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the try though. But did you saw the video in the main question? That can solve the issue. And that's what I am trying to do with no success.